A function in R studio that lets me get the average selling prices for all car brands?
I am working with this package,
Vehicle sales data
I am interested in looking at the average selling price of all the specific brands that have been sold for a price >50.000.
To do this, I loaded in the datacar_prices <- read.csv("car_prices.csv"), filtering out the all the selling prices < 50.000 using
sample1 = filter(car_prices, sellingprice>50000)

and then I filtered out the blanks by creating a second dataset using the code,
sample2 = filter(sample1, make!='')

However, when I try to plot my data to see the average prices for each car brand using the code,
ggplot(data = sample2, aes(x = make, y = sellingprice)) + 
geom_histogram(stat = "identity")

The resulting graph bundles all the prices for X car brand (make) together, resulting in some car brands reaching the millions.
I understand that I missed a step where I need to calculate the average of each car brand (make) in the "sample2" dataset. I am not sure how to do that, however, so any help is appreciated. And yes, I am a beginner.

There are many methods to get the mean by group at the linked FAQ. I'd recommend using a dplyr method, sample2 |> summarize(mean_price = mean(sellingprice), .by = make).
